# How to iterate over the rows, columns and planes of a tensor?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm trying to iterate over the output tensor in a custom operator. So far I only see the approach to flatten the tensor and iterate over it.

Is there a better way so I can iterate over the rows, columns and planes?

```
auto output = output_tensor->flat<float>();

// I would like to iterate through the dimensions here
const int N = output.size();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   output(i) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eigen Tensor library is documented ate the bottom of this page:

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/f6382682565c946d46612fe0e36e486bba1371ce/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/?at=default

From your question, I think you'll want to look at the chip and slice operations.

Comment: Try to include more than a link. While linking to the docs is useful, write your answer in such a way that it can stand alone